# How to remove the space between the lines

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a string with space between the lines, like this:

```
prepre imprimé ...



Epreuve contrôle éléctronique
```

how can i remove the space between the two.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would use `preg_replace` for this.

```
$yourOutput = preg_replace('/[\n\r]+/', '', $yourInput);
```

This should normally do the job. I prefer `preg_replace` instead of str_replace due to the fact, that you can use a regular expression which is often easier to expand.

Answer (score 2):

SImply use str_replace like this:-

```
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $var);
```